# How to remove redundant <br /> tags from HTML code using PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I'm parsing some messy HTML code with PHP in which there are some redundant 
 tags and I would like to clean them up a bit. For instance:

```
<br>

<br /><br /> 


<br>
```

How would I replace something like that with this using preg_replace()?:

```
<br /><br />
```

Newlines, spaces, and the differences between `<br>`, `<br/>`, and `<br />` would all have to be accounted for.

**Edit: Basically I'd like to replace every instance of three or more successive breaks with just two.**

Comment: how are you distinguishing between which is redundant and which is not?

Comment: Basically I'd like to replace every instance of three or more successive breaks with just two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is something you can use. The first line finds whenever there is 2 or more `<br>` tags (with whitespace between and different types) and replace them with wellformated `<br /><br />`.

I also included the second line to clean up the rest of the `<br>` tags if you want that too.

```
function clean($txt)
{
    $txt=preg_replace("{(<br[\\s]*(>|\/>)\s*){2,}}i", "<br /><br />", $txt);
    $txt=preg_replace("{(<br[\\s]*(>|\/>)\s*)}i", "<br />", $txt);
    return $txt;
}
```

Comment: Just one more thing, if you change the `<br /><br />` in the first replace to `<p />` you can get an even better output (html vice, not sure if you plan to display it or not).

Answer (score 5):

This should work, using minimum specifier:

```
preg_replace('/(<br[\s]?[\/]?>[\s]*){3,}/', '<br /><br />', $multibreaks);
```

Should match appalling `<br><br /><br/><br>` constructions too.

Comment: That's almost perfect, but yes it's choking on the <br> tags.

Comment: Added a bit more to it; not perfect as would match `<br >` too

Comment: Hmm. It seems to not be working for something like this:

<br> \n \n \n \n<br><br>

Comment: Added an optional number of spaces between breaks, does this work?

Comment: Does it work for not only spaces but newlines as well? In any case, it seems to be working pretty well. I've only got one more bit of trouble: "</p><br /><br /><ul class='blurbs'>". This results in a 3-4 unwanted newlines, but I think I can handle it on my own. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

this will replace all breaks ... even if they're in uppercase:

```
preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', '', $string);
```

Comment: See the comment I gave to hsz. I'm assuming it's the same case.

Comment: Its also worth noting the danger that this will match tags such as `<br clear="all">` or similar constructs which may not want to be collapsed fully. This may nto be relevant in this case of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
preg_replace('/<br\s*\/?>/', '', $inputString);
```

Comment: This removes all break tags, correct? If so, this is not what I need. I would like to replace any instance of three or more successive break tags with just two.

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace, its much better for simple replacement, and you can also pass an array instead of a single search value.

```
$newcode = str_replace("<br>", "", $messycode);
```

Comment: Author wrote: Basically I'd like to replace every instance of three or more successive breaks **with just two**.

Comment: Thanks, but simple replacement is unfortunately not what I need. I guess my initial post was a bit confusing.