# Redundant tags to be removed

Tags: php, html, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cleaning HTML by removing extra/redundant formatting tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248166/cleaning-html-by-removing-extra-redundant-formatting-tags)

I have been trying to remove redundant tags which are generated from HTML composers. This apparently is not able to remove all the empty ones. I have been looking at it for sometime and I am not able to figure out. There might be something I am missing.

Below is the code. Thanks a lot ppl..

```
//Check for reduntant tags
function removeRedundantTags($pathname) {
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($pathname);
$allTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
for($i = 0; $i < $allTags->length; $i++) {
    $currentTag = $allTags->item($i);
    echo "Accessed Tags: ".$currentTag->nodeName.'<br>';
    if($currentTag->hasChildNodes()) continue;
    if($currentTag->nodeName == 'br' || $currentTag->nodeName == 'img' || $currentTag->nodeName == 'meta') continue;
    if($currentTag->nodeValue == NULL) {                        
        $parentNode = $currentTag->parentNode;
        $oldChild = $parentNode->removeChild($currentTag);      
        echo "Removed Tags----: ".$oldChild->nodeName.'<br>';
    }
}   
echo "Redandant Removed<br>";
$dom->saveHTMLFile($pathname);
}
```

**Edit** (output added)
Lets saying I am trying to cleanup 
       span tags (sorry I am not able to post HTML code) 
It is just removing half of it.. 
It is like two of the span tags are present it removes only one, and the same applies to all of the empty tags

I am using DOM structure which happens to be very fast as I will be using this piece of code to hundreds of HTML files. So some of the answers use regular expressions which are not helpful.

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/ - should also help deal with spiteful users attempting to insert XSS attacks (or whatever).

Comment: It would probably help if you also post a sample input, the output you expect and the output you get.

Comment: I understand, I went through those but the code I am working on is PHP, and this code is eluding me!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function clean($txt)
{
    $txt=preg_replace("{(<br[\\s]*(>|\/>)\s*){2,}}i", "<br /><br />", $txt);
    $txt=preg_replace("{(<br[\\s]*(>|\/>)\s*)}i", "<br />", $txt);
    return $txt;
}
```

Answer by H9kDroid in [How to remove redundant <br /> tags from HTML code using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226216/how-to-remove-redundant-br-tags-from-html-code-using-php)

Comment: using regular expressions might be slower.. I will be applying this code to hundreds of HTML files.
I would like to use DOM structure to remove which happens to be super fast