# How to replace all <br /> using str_replace?

Tags: php

New to this, I'm trying (and failing) to use str_replace to replace all 
 tags in an html page.

In trying to learn what I'm doing, I can use it with echo to output a modified phrase... but not to replace anything.

I'm using: I'm using <?php // $el = str_replace('<br />', '', $el); ?>

My very limited understanding is that...

```
< ?php
$str_rep = "This is the original phrase";
echo str_replace("original","modified",$str_rep);
?>
```

... will modify and display a phrase wherever the code is positioned, but I don't understand how to modify/use to change something already in the code.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes, then show us to help you.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove redundant <br /> tags from HTML code using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226216/how-to-remove-redundant-br-tags-from-html-code-using-php)

Comment: @Gareth Parker... Using <?php // $el = str_replace('<br />', '', $el); ?>.

Comment: @  Rohan Kumar... Question updated to show the code I'm using. And the other post you mention largely refers to preg_replace and I can't understand the bit about str_replace.

Comment: @ Script47... Yes, I've read docs but can't understand how to use.

Comment: Did you realize that you commented your code out with the double slashes?

Comment: i can see two possible missunderstandings here: 1. `$modified =  str_replace('x','y', $original)` - str_replace doesn't alter the $orignial, but returns a modified string 2. there is no easy way to access the html text outside of <?php ?> tags

Answer (score 1):

It's rather easy:

```
echo str_replace("<br/>","something else",$text);
```

Please google before asking on SO.

Comment: From your answer, I can't understand what to use. And I searched and experimented extensively before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good to me. I used this:

```
<?php 
$el = 'Some text with tags.<br />and no other things<br />Nice!'; 
$el = str_replace('<br />', '', $el); 
echo $el;
```

and it outputs:

> Some text with tags.and no other thingsNice!

Maybe your input is not correct or you are trying to replace the wrong (written) tag?

Comment: I understand how to use it to echo something, but not to modify existing code.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do. What is "existing code"?

Comment: By 'existing code' I mean whatever html/text a page contains. In this instance, I have an html page containing elements produced elsewhere and which I can't remove by simply editing the html. If I've understood str_replace properly, I can add a bit of php to the page and it'll modify things - so in this way I'm hoping to use it to remove some unwanted br tags from code which I can't directly edit.

Comment: As I understand now what you are trying to do is not possible, Since the HTML is not rendered while executing str_replace, you cannot replace anything. You need to replace the tags before the output is sent to the browser. If you want to change the rendered output you need to use JavaScript instead. But maybe I am getting you wrong. Do you have access to the HTML content - maybe in a variable or return value?

Comment: @Phillip... Thanks. I now realise that my initial understanding of it was wrong... I thought it would work in a 'global search and replace' way, through a single bit of php positioned somewhere in the code. I now know that I have to position it directly where the replacement is to happen... hence my confusion with the 'echo' bit. So, I think I now understand enough to use it properly.